# Two Partial Views with the same select tag helper not working

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I've a [Bootstrap Tabs menu](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) in a `View`. The panels for tab 1 and tab2 have two partial views pv1 and pv2 each of which has a [Select tag helper](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx). As we know `asp-for` attribute of a tag helper creates an id and name attribute with same value as explained in the above article. Now, when I click on tab 1 the pv1 is rendered with a select tag helper. And, when I click on tab2, pv2 is rendered with a select tag helper. Both tag helpers are the same (list of years) but the years are selected for different purposes in tab1 and tab2 respectively. **Problem**: Whatever year is selected in pv1 select tag helper, the data in pv2 is filtered based on the that year rather than filtering on the year user selects on pv2 select tag helper. **Question**: Why? and how can I resolve the issue? How to Test: When I click on the `GO` button in pv2 the the Ajax code below always popups the alert with the year selected in pv2's select tag helper.

**Please Note** The real scenario has more than two tabs, and partial view in each tab panel has the same select tag helper and same `GO` button. I'm using the JQuery's [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so as to simplify my code and not write separate Ajax call for each `GO` button. Moreover, in my `ViewModel` - that is passed to the view - I want to use only one property for years list and selected year.

**ViewModel**:

```
public int entityid {get; set;}
 ...
public SelectList lstYears {get; set;}
public int SelectedYear {get; set;}
...
```

**View**:

```
<ul id="myTabstripID" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li id="AddprojTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li id="UpdPorjTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div id="menuAP" class="tab-pane in active">
       <div class="AddTabContenData"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="menuUP" class="tab-pane in active">
       <div class="UpdTabContenData"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Partial View1:**

```
    ...some html here
 Select Order Year: <select asp-for="SelectedYear" asp-items="@Model.lstYears"></select><button type="button" class="btnGO btn btn-default">GO</button>
    ...some html here to display data based on year selected in pv1
```

**Partial View2:**

```
    ...some html here
Select Delivery Year: <select asp-for="SelectedYear" asp-items="@Model.lstYears"></select><button type="button" class="btnGO btn btn-default">GO</button>
    ...some html here to display data based on year selected in pv2
```

**Ajax Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tab-content').on('click', '.btnGO', function (event) {
        var btnVal = $(this).val();
        var selectedYearVal = $('#SelectedYear').val();
        alert(selectedYearVal);
        $.ajax({
            ...
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` attributes (both your `<select>` elements have `id="SelectedYear"`) which is invalid html and in your script

```
var selectedYearVal = $('#SelectedYear').val();
```

will only ever return the value of the first element with `id="SelectedYear"`.

Ideally you should use view models with different property names (`asp-for` generates the `id` attribute based on the name of the property) but if that is not practical, your can specify the attribute in the html, for example

```
<select asp-for="SelectedYear" id="someValue" ... >
```

However, since you have a `<button class="btnGO" ... >` element in each partial, you should remove the `id` attribute and use a class name instead, and then use relative selectors. You partials should have a container element, say

```
<div class="container">
    <select asp-for="SelectedYear" asp-items="@Model.lstYears" class="year" id=""></select>
    <button type="button" class="btnGO btn btn-default">GO</button>
    ....
</div>
```

and modify the script to get the selected option in the dropdownlist relative to the button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-content').on('click', '.btnGO', function (event) {
        // var btnVal = $(this).val(); 
        var container = $(this).closest('.container');
        var selectedYearVal = container.find('.year').val();
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Note also that `var btnVal = $(this).val();` does not make sense since the `<button>` does not have a `value` attribute

Comment: It worked like a charm. What came handy in my case was the already existing class `tab-pane` in Bootstrap Tabstrip. And in my case since tab pane is a container for the partial, I just used `tab-pane` in your code and it worked. Thanks for providing necessary but to the point details.

Comment: So, two classes `tab-content` and `tab-pane` from Bootstrap came handy for me in this particular example and in your code.